# how to write .htaccess for multiple domains

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new and I need some help on `.htaccess`. I've search for hours already and I can't find a solution.

So basically, we own several domains but we only have one hosting service. On the root directory we have a wordpress site installed and working just fine let us say it has domain1.com.

We added a sub directory, put a system (custom made php system) and added a domain on it (let's say domain2.com). this is working just fine if we access `domain2.com/page.php`

But the way we set up the system is that we only want to show domain2.com/page on the url and we are just `include_once` the `page.php`.

What is happening right now, if we are going to `domain2.com/page` it goes to the wordpress site telling us that page doesn't exist. Which is true.

I've read about .htaccess but I can't seem to figure out what to put in there. we tried several suggestion from the internet but it is not working. currently this is the .htaccess on the root folder

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

We tried to remove the lines

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

but it is still redirecting us to the wordpress page.

I hope I'm explaining myself well. And I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: htaccess files are applied in the order they're encountered while scanning DOWN the filesystem tree. The .htaccess for your main `domain1` site is probably intercepting and taking over ALL requests for your `domain2` sub-domain. You need to explicily excempt that subdirectory from your main site's htaccess rules.

Comment: Have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: @MarcB Thats what im thinking as well, but we cant figure out what to put on htaccess to exempt. I apologize for our ignorance. Any ideas?

Comment: @RobinWebdev i think the vhost are already working since if we are going to access the php file directly like domain2.com/page.php we can access it without a problem.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/path/to/subdir`?

Comment: @MarcB, so basically that condition will check if the subdir exist right? im not sure how that gonna solve the problem :(

Comment: you put into your parent domain's htaccess. it'll say "ignore anything that's going into the subdomain"

Answer (score 1):

basically in your root folder (the publish_html) you should not put any of your websites.
lets say you have 2 website, web1 and web2.
create a folder public_html/web1.com (the .com is just a common convention) and
public_html/web2.com.

put each website files in each folder, remmeber that each website has it's own files,framework,.htaccess etc.

the routing for domain web1.com to the folder web1.com and web2.com to the folder web2.com should be in the server itself, in the vhost, NOT in the htaccess.
if you are using cPanel you can just go to add domain and when you add a domain you can set the folder for the domain. so define a new domain web1.com and add it to public_html/web1.com. same for web2.com

Comment: If you're not on cPanel, and have access to the apache configuration, check out vhosts (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: Right, but remember that different linuxes have a different locations of file so check you linux type and version

Comment: @zionbenyacov we are on godaddy so the main folder is tied with a domain. This is something we cant change. if we are going to put the wordpress site on a folder, thats gonna be domain.com/foldername and we dont want that. Any more suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is seriously not to work with goDaddy as host server. I have domains there but my host is in hostGator, they are create, chip and comes with cPanet, it's like 7,8$ a month, if the hosting is tied to the domain it's a big of a problem because you can put project per folder

Comment: @CurtisMattoon i think the vhost are already working since if we are going to access the php file directly like domain2.com/page.php we can access it without a problem.

Comment: Changing the host server is something beyond my control, Im working with a client and he already have a year subscription i think..